# how i can implement paypal Delayed Chained adaptive payment integration.

Tags: php, cakephp

I need quick help regarding how i can integrate delayed chained payment method of adaptive payments integration of paypal.

Currently i can transfer total amount to one account(Primary-reciever), by setting up actionType=>'PAY_PRIMART', but i need help how i can process payments to secondary recievers.

Thanks,
AnuP Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You should Use NVP API and call Pay method https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI 
Please, use actionType = 'PRIMARY' to create delayed payment.

You recieve payKey key in result array. Use this key to make ExecutePayment request https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APExecutePaymentAPI.

After this request execution money will be seneded to secondary reciever.

Comment: Hey @neyronius  ...please can you paste here payload in each case to be more clear. Many thanks in advance.